# Creating a variable and using it in HTML code in Google Scripts

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way to use a variable in Google Scripts HTML Code? Right now I have:

```
var activeUser = Session.getActiveUser()
app.add(app.createHTML("<h1>Hello, activeUser </h1>"));
```

This doesn't work. Is there a way to make this work? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
var activeUser = Session.getActiveUser()
app.add(app.createHTML("<h1>Hello, " + activeUser + "</h1>"));
```